# How to paginate JSON results using PHP

Tags: php, json, github, pagination

i'm using the Github API to get the repositorie commits, but i want to paginate the results.
The data is on JSON and i want to do the pagination style like this:

[image]

the api resutls: http://api.github.com/repos/FenixHosting/docs.fenixcms.com/commits

Edit:
I have a function but it don't work:

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 20,$page = 1, $url = '?', $custom){
        $git_docs = file_get_contents($query, false);
        $row = json_decode($git_docs, true);
        $total = count($row);
        $adjacents = "2"; 

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               

        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm'>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><span>...</span></li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>»</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a>»</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class='disabled'><a>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";      
        }


        return $pagination;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pagination` feature of their API - https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the ?page parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the ?per_page parameter.

Eg - https://api.github.com/repos/FenixHosting/docs.fenixcms.com/commits?page=1&per_page=3

To construct the pagination links, read this: https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#constructing-pagination-links

Comment: I have that clear, but i want to do the pagination style from the image